# Playwright promise.all returning page/context?

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise, playwright, destructuring

So I saw a bit of confused and I was a bit confused what it was doing:

```
 private async SwitchPage(): Promise<Page> {
        const [newWindow] = await Promise.all([
            await this.context.waitForEvent("page")
        ]);
        await newWindow.waitForLoadState();
        console.log(`switched to new window ${await newWindow.title()}`);
        return newWindow;
    };
```

I saw this in a Playwright sample demo/project. Im not used to using `promise.all` in general, so Im a little bit confused what the `const [newWindow]` exactly is? I'd assume it's the return type of whatever is enclosed in the `promise.all` block. But according to playwright: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-wait-for-event
It seems to just return a regular object, and not some sort of context or page?

But maybe im missing something here. How is this person chaining `waitForLoadState()` off what is just a base object and not specifically a browser context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` is designed to resolve after all promises in its argument array are resolved. It returns a promise that resolves to an array, which can be destructured. The `Promise.all` here is pointless for two reasons:

1. only a single item is in the array and
2. the item that's in the array isn't a promise because it was already `await`ed.

The following simpler code is functionally identical:

```js
private async SwitchPage(): Promise<Page> {
  const newWindow = await this.context.waitForEvent("page");
  await newWindow.waitForLoadState();
  console.log(`switched to new window ${await newWindow.title()}`);
  return newWindow;
};
```

> It seems to just return a regular object, and not some sort of context or page?

`waitForEvent()` returns a promise that resolves (via `await`) to an `Object`, which in this case is a `Page` instance. The reason for the generic `Object` typing is because different parameter `event` names can return different types of objects, not just `Page`s.

> How is this person chaining `waitForLoadState()` off what is just a base object and not specifically a browser context?

It's a `Page`, which is known to TS because of the return value type `Promise<Page>`. `Page`s have `.waitForLoadState()` and `.title()` methods, among other things.

> I saw this in a Playwright sample demo/project

I would hesitate to trust the quality of this sample demo/project, as this usage of `Promise.all` indicates that the author isn't familiar with promise fundamentals. This is a red flag.

---

If you're curious about the destructuring syntax, any function that returns an array, such as an `await`ed `Promise.all`, can be destructured:

```js
const a = [42, 1];
const [x, y] = a;
console.log(x, y); // => 42 1
```

Here's a more sensible use of `Promise.all`, following the same principle:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms)
);

(async () => {
  const [x, y] = await Promise.all([
    sleep(1000), // note: no `await`!
    sleep(3000),
  ]);
  console.log(x, y); // => 1000, 3000
})();
```

To emphasize that the destructuring syntax is purely cosmetic, the following is functionally the same as above, except without destructuring:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms)
);

(async () => {
  const durations = await Promise.all([
    sleep(1000), // note: no `await`!
    sleep(3000),
  ]);
  const x = durations[0];
  const y = durations[1];
  console.log(x, y); // => 1000, 3000
})();
```

Comment: Old comment, but why does in your sleep example the return of the sleep function the duration (in ms) you passed in? Is it because a promise always returns the parameter thats passed in when it resolves?

Also how do we know in Playwright for example that the return Object type is a page? PW documentation just states a generic object? https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-event

Comment: It's a contrived example. I resolved the promises with their duration so there'd be something simple and identifiable to destructure that lets you see what's going on. Normally, sleeping doesn't return anything, so destructuring would be pointless. `waitForEvent` can return different objects depending on the event you wait on (specified by a string), so its typing is a generic Object to account for the arbitrary use cases.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the playwright docs don't specifically state the type of the object. But I guess if it's within the page API it's probably returning a type of `page`

Comment: My earlier comment may not have been clear. The docs _can't_ specifically state the type of the object because there's no way to know in advance what the "event data value" type may be. A plain object is the best they can do here. In their example, `page.waitForEvent('download')` returns a download, not a page, so I wouldn't count on it usually returning anything. I suggest not getting too hung up on that return type.

Answer (score 1):

In general the [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will only resolve once all promises in its array have resolved which may happen simultaneously.

Simple example to self-explain:

```
const p1 = getSomeValueAsync();
const p2 = getSomeValueAsync();

const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);//result1 & result2 are values returned when both p1 & p2 promises are resolved.

console.log(result1 + result2);
```